# Without using slam gmapping!

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I just want to know whether we can give **our predefined map of an office room without using slam gmapping**? I want to use laser and camera in the robot, and with the help of both obstacles of the given map can be avoided?
Will it be a problem if I want to **write my own navigation stack with my own map?**

I am using USARSim simulator on windows& and ROS Groovy on Ubuntu11.10.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/78691/without-using-slam-gmapping!!/) by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2013-09-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. You don't really mention it in your question, but I guess you want the robot to localize itself on a given a map using lidar data? For that I suggest having a look at http://wiki.ros.org/amcl
2. It's all open source, everything is possible :). You can of course write your own navigation stack. However, there are already solutions available in ROS for mapping/localization/path planning/obstacle avoidance.

---

Originally posted by [jodafo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1732/jodafo/) with karma: 365 on 2013-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2013-09-28**:
If I don't want to go for amcl as well and try to build a visibility graph (or occupancy map) from sensor data, then will it be a problem ? # jodafo